# How to make Safari Frequently Visited Sites work and Safari syncing tabs on iOS 14.6 and Catalina

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

A few weeks back I had to wipe my iPhone and restore to factory settings.  I then did a clean install.  Since then I have gotten no Frequently Visited Sites to show on Safari on my phone.  I have Frequently Visited Sites enabled in Settings, Safari.

Is there some other setting I need to have on to have this feature work?  I am getting no Frequently Visited Sites showing in Safari.

Apple Senior Tech said, just use bookmarks but I prefer this feature.....  I have iOS 14.6
This is where they should be, right??

[image]

Oddly , I just noticed I don’t have this feature on my iPad either. Maybe they don’t  offer it anymore and no one knows??

Could this be by chance a cloud sync issue?  I don't think Frequently Visited Sites sync via cloud, but I noticed too last night that my cloud tabs are not working properly either - seem to have older ones keep showing but I don't get any new / current ones to appear.  Also, I now have noticed 2 tabs that I had pinned in MBP safari but have since unpinned, won't stop from showing in cloud safari tabs.  Multiple issues here.....
[image]
[image]

Comment: so ive taken care of the unpinned tabs not going away.  Signed out of icloud and unchecked safari in icloud settings then signed back in and re-checked Safari in icloud and did not merge info.  But still no luck in getting Frequently Visited Sited to work.  Anyone?

Comment: still trying to get safari Frequently Visited Sites to register/work.  Either nothing ever shows there or 1 site and thats it....  Is there something in the Library I can check or reset or something?